# Cljs: Hardcode the compilation date at compilation time

Tags: compilation, clojurescript

Would somebody give me hints (or the entire solution!) to this question:

In a Clojurescript project, how can I automatically hardcode the compilation date/time in a symbol for it to be displayed when the app is used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple solutions:

### Use [lein-git-version](https://github.com/cvillecsteele/lein-git-version) plugin

Add lein-git-version plugin to your project. It will generate a namespace containing vars with information like project version, git revision and timestamp. You can refer to them from other namespaces.

### Use a macro

You can define a macro in a `.clj` or `.cljc` file:

```
(defmacro generate-build-timestamp []
  (System/currentTimeMillis))
```

And use it in your ClojureScript code:

```
(def build-timestamp (generate-build-timestamp))
```

As the macro code will be executed during compilation, the value produced by the macro will be filled in the the compiled JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks, lein-git-version was what I needed. I would have preferred your second and simpler solution but couldn't make it work with js/Date. Maybe it HAS to be in a .clj file?

Comment: @Gra Macros and ClojureScript compilation run on JVM thus you can't call JavaScript APIs in macros. You can modify your ClojureScript code to: `(def build-timestamp (js/Date. (generate-build-timestamp)))` or have your macro to emit the code with `js/Date.` constructor call: `(defmacro generate-build-timestamp [] (list 'js/Date. (System/currentTimeMillis)))`.